# After updating my web server digicert certificate, browsers only get 'insecure' message with PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

My Windows 2012 IIS 8, now fails to connect with all clients.  This started today when the server certificate expired, even though I had installed a new one (exp 2023) a month ago.  Today, browsers get the "insecure" message about site not supporting https due to expired certificate.  When I double-click the newest certificate, from IIS:Server Certificates, all 3 tabs say the certificate is good: GeoTrust TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020-CA-1.
I deleted two old certificates (2021 and expired-yesterday) and rebooted.  Now the message browsers get is PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR.
I used IIS Crypto GUI and applied 'best practices' for both SChannel and Cipher Suites and rebooted, to no avail.
[image: Schannel]
Cipher suites has all thru TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA selected, and none after that (image too large).

Any suggestions on why a correctly installed new certificate would just not work are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you have to go into site bindings and re-select a certificate.  It does not simply roll over to the updated certificate.  I thought it would with the same name.  Argh.  I hope this saves someone else an hour or two.

Comment: You need to fully understand how Windows/IIS binds certificates to site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background and then you will know changing the actual certificate mappings are the key. Anyone following DigiCert docs won't miss that step either, https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-certificate-renewal-iis-10.htm as "Assign the SSL Certificate" is highlighted.